# Redis pattern to find only numeric keys

Tags: redis

I have below keys in my redis database

- test
- 123
- test123
- 456
- test456

I just need to retrieve only numeric keys like below:

- 123
- 456

Any Solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/19c8393f465b62c9cfa8

Comment: notice, that SCAN/Lua based solution will scan all the keys and filter according to given template, if you need some way to index the data you should check https://redisearch.io

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a key-Value store, so ideally you should know the key for which you want to fetch the data. But still, if you want to fetch multiple keys then you can do below.

1. Create a Key, whose value saves all the numeric keys.

   Key: Value

   numKeys: 123, 456, 789
2. Then fetch the value of numKeys, i.e. get(numKeys) -> 123, 456, 789. Then do a mget, i.e. mget 123 456 789

This wil have two round trips but sill much better than running a lua script on server. This is because a) lua blocks the server b) lua will scan the entire key space where the above approach is fast as it uses key based retrieval.